# Running multiple shell instances with different parameters at the same time

Tags: shell-script, osx, memory, virtual-memory

Assume I have a python script that I want to run with different parameter combinations (I have MacBook Pro). If I use a shell script to do so (say `run.sh`), does it make sense to run `run.sh` multiple times at the same time, each of which in different parameter combinations? In order word, do different parameter combinations touch each other while both are running in the memory? Is this something like the concept of memory protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends very much on what the python script and `run.sh` does.

So let's take a very simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

s=$(( RANDOM%5 ))
echo Sleeping for $s > /tmp/foo
sleep $s
echo You entered $1 >> /tmp/foo
cat /tmp/foo
```

Now if I did

```
./run.sh 1 &
./run.sh 2 &
./run.sh 3 &
```

I will have no idea what the output would be.  That's because the script has a single resource (`/tmp/foo`) that can not be accessed multiple times; one script will overwrite the results of another.

If, instead, the script was written to use properly unique "temporary" resources then it can be called multiple times:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=$(mktemp)

s=$(( RANDOM%5 ))
echo Sleeping for $s > $tmpfile
sleep $s
echo You entered $1 >> $tmpfile
cat $tmpfile
rm $tmpfile
```

Now you can call this as many times as you like, and it will work properly.

Well... given memory and CPU limits, of course!